# Subscribing to event but wanting to get initial value

Tags: prism

I have a question about prism. I have the main app with ViewModel and a module with business logic. I have set up events in the module for properties that I want to be updated in the main apps ViewModel. On ViewModel load, I subscribe to all the events that are in the Module. I want to get those initial values of the in those properties when they got published on the Module Initialization but I am not sure how to do that. Could someone help me understand how it's supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot receive events that were published before you subscribed. But you should have a service that provides the current values, anyway, so just inject it into the view model and get the initial values from there.

Comment: Is there an example if the prism docs to figure out services? I am using prism with wpf.

Comment: That's not really Prism-related... you have services in most applications. Essentially, a service is a class with an interface, registered as singleton and used by multiple consumers (either view models or other services). I suggest you put your properties on such a singleton and inject it into the view model. For change notifications you can use event aggregator (as you do now) or have your service implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`...

Comment: I guess my issue is how do I initialize those services within prisms ApplicationBase. Should I be adding it to IserviceLocator or where do I place it exactly?

Comment: Override `RegisterTypes` (in you application and your modules, if you have some) and register your services and everything with the given `IContainerRegistry`...